# Scikit SGD classifier with Hashing Vectorizer accuracy stuck at 58%

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying my hand in Machine Learning and have been using python based Scikit library for it.

I wish to solve a 'Classification' problem in which a chunk of text (say of 1k-2k words) is classified into one or more category. For this I have been studying scikit for a while now.

As my data being in range 2-3 Million, so I was using SGDClassfier with HashingVectorizer for the purpose using partial_fit learning technique, coded as below:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import  SGDClassifier
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import HashingVectorizer
import numpy as np
from sklearn.externals import joblib
import copy

data = pd.read_csv(
    open('train_shuffled.csv'), error_bad_lines=False)
data_all = copy.deepcopy(data)
target = data['category']
del data['category']

cls = np.unique(target)
model = SGDClassifier(loss='log', verbose=1)
vect = HashingVectorizer(stop_words='english', strip_accents='unicode', analyzer='word')
loop = len(target) / 100
for passes in range(0, 5):
    count, r = 0, 0
    print("Pass " + str(passes + 1))
    for q in range(0, loop):
        d = nltk.word_tokenize(data['content'][r:r + 100])
        d = vect.fit_transform(d)
        t = np.array(target[r:r + 100])
        model.partial_fit(d, t, cls)
        r = r + 100
    data = copy.deepcopy(data_all)
    data = data.iloc[np.random.permutation(len(data))]
    data = data.reset_index(drop=True)
    target = data['category']
    del data['category']

print(model)
joblib.dump(model, 'Model.pkl')
joblib.dump(vect, 'Vectorizer.pkl')
```

While going the learning process, I read in an answer here on stack that manually randomizing the training data on each iteration results into better model.

Using the Classifers and Vectorizers with default parameters, I got an accuracy score of ~58.4%. Since then, I have trying playing with different parameter setting for both Vectorizer and Classifier but no increase in accuracy.

Is anyone able to tell me, if something is wrong I have been doing or what should be done for improving the model score.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1) consider using GridSearchCv to tune parameters. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html

2)consider feature engineering, to combine existing features into new features. E.G. use the polynomial features, feature selection and feature union tools provided in sklearn.

3) try different models. Not all models work on all problems. Try using an ensemble of simpler models and some kind of decision function to take the outputs of those models and make a prediction. Some are in the enesemble module, but you can use the voting classifiers to make your own.

but by far the best and most important thing to do, look at the data. Find examples of where the classifier performed badly. Why did it perform badly? Can you classify it from reading it (i.e. is it reasonable to expect an algo to classifier that text?). If it can be classified, what does the model miss.

All these will help guide what to do next.

Comment: GridSearchCV does not implements partial_fit method, which I was using because my training data set is too large. For feature-selection, I have pre-processed my training data removing all unimportant terms and also stemming each and every word. Can you specifically point out, what causes the accuracy of my model to stuck at ~58%? Thanks!

Comment: No I can't, because it could be one of a thousand reasons. How do you know that 58% is not the maximum achievable fit for your problem? 

What was the result of my last paragraph? I can't solve the problem for you, you have to do that yourself.